# Sublime Text Auto-Indent Python Keyword Arguments

Tags: python, sublimetext, sublimetext3, pep8

I'm having an issue making Sublime act the way I like with keyword arguments.
PEP-8 allows for two conventions for function calls:

```
function_name(
    arg=1,
    arg2=blah)
```

And:

```
function_name(arg=1,
              arg2=blah)
```

I much prefer the latter for lines less then 80 characters.  but Sublime Text 3 doesn't accommodate that well. When I hit Enter after the first line comma, indentation continues four spaces in:

```
function_name(arg=1,
    arg2=blah)
```

Is there a way to get the editor to align the cursor to the position just right of the open parenthesis?

Thanks!

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You need to change Sublime Text Preferences.

1. Open Preferences
2. Settings -> User
3. Add this line there:

> ```
> {"indent_to_bracket": true}
> ```

4. Restart Sublime

After this you code will be formated in this way:

```
def function(*arg, 
             **kwargs):
    #body
```

Answer (score 0):

Specifically for python 3.x

Tools->Command Palette-> Indentation: Convert to tabs

The entire file indentation will be converted to tabs from inconsistent indentation of tabs and spaces.

Comment: This is not, what the @frank asked for. The solution answers the question